# Is there a way to change the ubuntu login background wallpaper to a video?

Tags: login, video, lightdm, customization, desktop-background

I've been a bit obsessed with customizing Ubuntu. I have a really cool logo animation in a mp4 file. I'm trying to use that video as my login screen background，like Dreamscene in Windows. But I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

I Googled relevant information and noticed that LightDM can change login background to another image. I haven't seen any program that can make the login background a video though.

Answer (score 0):

The only Display Manager I know of that supports video backgrounds OOTB, is [SDDM](https://github.com/sddm)

It works (as evidenced by [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKwz2FQcE3c) video), but is not simple to install.

The basic process requires QT 5, and the code needs to be compiled.

Quote from the installation documentation:

> SDDM uses CMake to configure the build and it can be compiled with the
>   typical cmake build process:
>
> ```
> mkdir build
> cd build
> cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
> make
> ```
>
> After successfully building the software, type following to install.
>
> ```
> sudo make install
> ```
>
> When found, systemd will be used for power management. When systemd is
>   not available build will fallback to using upower. If upower can not
>   be found either, shutdown/reboot/suspend/hibernate actions won't be
>   available. Note that, when systemd found, HaltCommand and
>   RebootCommand config file entries has no effect.

Comment: I found an similar examplee too, as in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWdA6ZdRfmY

Comment: And a tutorial showing how to install sddm on Ubuntu. Not sure if this is doable: http://linuxpitstop.com/install-sddm-on-ubuntu-15-04-and-linux-mint/

Comment: @user262072 - It's definitely plausible, but whether you want to go to that amount of trouble, I leave in your capable hands :)

Comment: @user262072 - No problems. If you find the answer you're looking for, don't forget to accept the answer you find most appropriate for your question.  Good luck! :)