# Ubuntu login screen customization - show an animation when correct credentials are entered

Tags: 20.04, login, login-screen, gdm

I know we can customize the Ubuntu 20.04 login background, however I want to develop something slightly different.

I would like, when the user enters a correct login and credential and then click the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> button, to see the login image being animated.

It should be like if the log in picture was a video in pause, which is only played when a user successfully enters credentials and hits the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> button.

Does it sound doable?

Comment: See this -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/370624/use-video-for-wallpaper Or, this -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/851783/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-ubuntu-login-background-wallpaper-to-a-video I hope this may be useful for you and other people viewing this question.

Comment: This is not exactly what I need, but it can be a good alternative.